# Typescript issue with dynamic keys in object referencing react components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typescript complains that expression of type 'string' can't be used to index '{ bg: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">>; de: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">>; ... 7 more ...; tr: OverridableComponent<...>; }'

How should we proceed in such a case?

```
import {
  BulgariaFlag,
  FranceFlag,
  GermanyFlag,
  GreatBritainFlag,
  GreeceFlag,
  ItalyFlag,
  RomaniaFlag,
  RussiaFlag,
  SpainFlag,
  TurkeyFlag,
} from "../Icon";

const flagIcons = {
  bg: BulgariaFlag,
  de: GermanyFlag,
  en: GreatBritainFlag,
  es: SpainFlag,
  fr: FranceFlag,
  gr: GreeceFlag,
  it: ItalyFlag,
  ro: RomaniaFlag,
  ru: RussiaFlag,
  tr: TurkeyFlag,
};

const EmployeeItem: React.FC<{ company: Company; employee: User }> = ({
  company,
  employee,
}) => {
 return 
   <span>
              {employee.spokenLanguages.map((spokenLanguage) => {
                const FlagIcon = flagIcons[spokenLanguage];

                  <FlagIcon
                    key={spokenLanguage}
                    viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                    titleAccess={t(`fields.spokenLanguages.${spokenLanguage}`)}
                  />
              })}
            </span>
};

export default EmployeeItem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that `User.spokenLanguages` is array of `string` whereas it should really be array of `"bg" | "de" | ... | "ru" | "tr"`. You have three solutions

1. Change `User.spokenLanguages` to be of type `("bg" | "de" | ... | "ru" | "tr")[]` instead of `string[]`
2. When rendering, check if `language` is a valid key of `flagIcons` using a type guard

```
const isValidLanguage = (str: string): str is keyof typeof flagIcons => str in flagIcons

{employee.spokenLanguages.map(language => {
  if(!isValidLanguage(language)) return null

  const FlagIcon = flagIcons[language]
  return ...
})}
}
```

3. Use `const flagIcon: Record<string, ComponentType<TypeOfPropsOfYourIcons> = {...}`. Please consider not doing this, as it can cause runtime errors if `language` is some string that is not in `flagIcon`.

Comment: Solution 2 is the most flexible and will future-proof your code against having to update the union type proposed by solution 1. For a more strongly typed `User` interface, you could also make `User.spokenLanguages` have type `(keyof typeof flagIcons)[]` but this could pose problems if new languages are added before you have the chance to update `flagIcons`